# Linkedin "Scope" Variable not set

Tags: spring-social

I'm having trouble setting up a connection to Linkedin Api using Spring Social.

I am passing the "scope" variable "r_emailaddress" as a hidden field with the form to retrieve the email address but it's not working - I don't see the email_address permission like you do here. https://developer.linkedin.com/sites/default/files/gp-dialog.png

I am following the Spring Social Showcase Application Example.  I should add, the Social Application there is no hidden scope field.

It works fine with Facebook.

Form

```
<form name="linkedinin_signin" id="linkedin_signin" action="${linkedin_uri}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress" />
    <input type="image" src="${linkedin_img_uri}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct that LinkedIn is an OAuth 1.0a provider and that the "scope" parameter is non-standard with regard to OAuth 1.0(a). Therefore, Spring Social did not recognize the scope parameter for OAuth 1.0(a) providers.

However, you may be interested to know that yesterday I pushed a change to Spring Social that will allow any arbitrary parameter to be passed along to the request token URL and the authorization URL...including the "scope" parameter. This change, being relatively new, is only available in the latest 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT builds, but will soon make an appearance in 1.1.0.M2. This should address your need.

You may also want to look at the Spring Social Showcase example, as it now uses the "scope" parameter to request "r_emailaddress" scope when a user connects to LinkedIn.

I'd appreciate any feedback you have on this change, preferably as comments to https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIAL-349 or in the Spring Social forum at http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?82-Social. (I do not monitor questions on StackOverflow nearly as often as I do on the Spring Social forum.)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with LinkedIn. Here is what I did to resolve it:

instead of

```
    final OAuth1Parameters params = new OAuth1Parameters();
    params.set("scope", "r_emailaddress r_basicprofile");
```

I had to send a map with the fetchRequestToken

```
    final MultiValueMap<String, String> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    mvm.add("scope", "r_emailaddress");
    mvm.add("scope", "r_basicprofile");
    inRequestToken = oauth1Operations.fetchRequestToken(redirectUri, mvm);
```

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn is recognized by SpringSecurity as OAuth1 provider. OAuth1 does not support "Access Token Scope" feature. So your scope parameter is silently ignored. Actually LinkedIn uses non official OAuth 1.0a protocol version that has support for scopes. As a workaround you can try to override some SpringSocial classes and send scope parameter to LinkedIn. See [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129684-Linked-In-member-permissions) thread.

Answer (score 0):

The oAuth1 API of linked in doesn't support the scope parameters at all, you must use oAuth2 - http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication - to be able to get the email address